# Different Latex is generated when changing a number from 2 to 1. Using HoldForm

Tags: formatting, hold, latex

This is the most bizzar thing I saw with Mathematica TeXForm.  Could someone please explain why it happens and if there is a workaround?

First, will show screen shot. I have an expression, when I have `2*x` in it, TeXForm generates `\exp` for `exp` when using `With[{...},TeXForm[HoldForm[...]]`. When changing `2*x` to `1*x`, now `e` Latex is generated, same as `TeXForm`

This only happens when using `With[{...},TeXForm[HoldForm[...]]` construct. Otherwise `TeXForm` works same in both cases.  But why?

[image]

Here is the code

```
ClearAll[x]

expr = 1/(Exp[(5*x - 2)/((10*x^2 - 10*x)*Exp[x] + (2*x))])
With[{z0 = expr},
  exprAsLatex = TeXForm[HoldForm[z0]];
  ];
exprAsLatex

expr = 1/(Exp[(5*x - 2)/((10*x^2 - 10*x)*Exp[x] + (1*x))])
With[{z0 = expr},
  exprAsLatex = TeXForm[HoldForm[z0]];
  ];
exprAsLatex
```

Using 12.3.1 on windows 10.

You might ask, why Am I using `HoldForm`? the reason is that this is part of larger code, where I needed to prevent evaluation of an expression while taking its Latex. The above is a MWE of the problem.

`TeXForm` works the same on both `2*x` and `1*x` :

[image]

The problem only shows up when using the `With[{...},TeXForm[HoldForm[...]]` method.

Comment: Why do you think there is no $\exp$ command in LaTeX?

Comment: @mmeent I just checked, yes, there is `\exp` in latex. I never used it and Mathematica did not use it before, that is why. All the CAS systems I use generate `e` for `exp`.  Still, why the difference in output is my main question. I'll adjust the question now.

Comment: `TeXForm` is just converting the `TraditionalForm` to LaTeX.  Replace `TeXForm` with `TraditionalForm` in your code to see this.  Why is `TraditionalForm` formatting these two expressions differently?  I don't know, that is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update to give a simpler fix**

As @jasonb says, [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) is based on [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), and [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) checks the [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount) of superscripts and uses `exp` instead of `e` when the [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount) is too large. I suppose the thinking is that enormous superscripts are less readable. Unfortunately, the limit at which this switchover occurs is not configurable. The simplest fix is to wrap [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E) in [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm):

```
expr = 1/(Exp[(5*x - 2)/((10*x^2 - 10*x)*Exp[x] + (2*x))]);
With[{z0 = expr},
    TeXForm[HoldForm[z0] /. E -> HoldForm[E]]
]
```

> e^{-\frac{-2+5 x}{2 x+e^x \left(-10 x+10 x^2\right)}}

Another possibility is to do surgery on the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) formatting rules, something like:

```
$SuperscriptLimit = 100;
Unprotect[TraditionalForm];
FormatValues[TraditionalForm] = FormatValues[TraditionalForm] /. 50 :> $SuperscriptLimit;
Protect[TraditionalForm];
```

Then:

```
expr = 1/(Exp[(5*x - 2)/((10*x^2 - 10*x)*Exp[x] + (2*x))]);
With[{z0 = expr},
    TeXForm[HoldForm[z0]]
]
```

> e^{-\frac{-2+5 x}{2 x+e^x \left(-10 x+10 x^2\right)}}

Comment: Thanks. Will use your method for work around. But why then `TeXForm` behaves differently outside the `With....HoldForm`? Since `LeafCount` did not change. It is the same expression.

Comment: @Nasser It is the `LeafCount` of the boxes that are generated. The `HoldForm` version has things like `RowBox[{RowBox[{"-", "2"}], "+", RowBox[{"5", " ", "x"}]}]` instead of `RowBox[{RowBox[{"5", " ", "x"}], "-", "2"}]`

Comment: May be Mathematica should consider using `LeafCount` of the actual raw expression, not including any formatting/wrappers overheads such as `RowBox`. That is what I think of, when using `LeafCount` on expression.   But your workaround worked. Thanks.